# display custom message on failed ssh server login

Tags: server, ssh

Is it possible to show a custom message **only** to users which failed to login into an openssh server?

```
successful login > no message  
failed login     > display message
```

Comment: See this question: [Custom error message for sshd](http://serverfault.com/q/286287)

Comment: @Nattgew So the answer is, it's not possible. If you want, just write a small answer and I will accept it (to give you some earned points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSH protocol includes the functionality to send messages, but OpenSSH doesn't have a way to send a custom message only for a failed login.

See this [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/286287/custom-error-message-for-sshd) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

for SSH :

put your text in a file, eg:

```
*****************************************************************
* Private SSH service.                                          *
* Please leave immediately.                                     *
*****************************************************************
```

In the sshd_conf file, find the line:

```
#Banner /etc/issue.net
```

Uncomment the line and change the path to your custom SSH banner text file.